# Included jars in wars take up a lot of space

Tags: websphere, war, tomahawk

we have a lot of projects for a lot of war files. Many of these projects have dependencies on tomahawk and jsf-ibm (they are Websphere wars) and thus have their respective jars included in WEB-INF/lib.

However, the size of the mentioned jars total to 4.6 M . This makes the resulting wars ridiculously large.

This wouldn't be an issue with a single war, however, we have about a 80 wars, resulting in  368 MB  worth of duplicate jars.

How can I reduce this size? Is there a way to have our wars use the 2 jars from a shared classpath?

PS. we do not use ears to install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WebSphere shared libraries.

You have to create them first: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftcws_sharedlib_create.html

Afterwards you can apply them to your application:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftcws_sharedlib_app.html